Pass nested std::array<std::array<char,M>,N> to C function taking a char**
I have a C function in an external library which takes a char** argument (a pointer to a list of pointers, each of which represents the first character of a nul-terminated C-string).
At the client level, my list of strings is a C++ nested std::array scheme on the stack of type:
std::array<std::array<char, MAX_LEN>, NUM_STRINGS>

Question:  What is the most elegant way to pass the nested std::array contents to the C function which takes the char**?
For a 1D std::array<T>, we have the .data() member which provides the T*.
Is there an analogous way to get a T** from a 2D std::array<std::array<T>> which doesn't involve allocating a new array of type char*[NUM_STRINGS] and copying each of the pointers to each inner element in a for loop (which is my current, but seemingly rather ugly and inefficient approach).

creating the array of pointers is the only way I know how to do it.  You can't just cast the 2d std::array to a char** so some manual work must be done

Is the C function expecting pointer to char arrays or just a 2D array of characters? They both may have the same signature(although the later case can be handled with better syntax too).

You need to understand, that types like char array[100][100]; and char **array; have completely different memory layout and can't be "just casted" from one to another.

Something I almost always do when switching from one technology (language/rpc) to another is to make sure I have "adapters" (classes or functions). So that in the C++ I can keep using the full C++ benefits and only adapt at the last moment to the other language (in this case "C").
For your case that would look like this :
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

void legacy_func(char** strings, size_t rows, size_t columns)
{
    for(size_t row = 0; row < rows; ++row)
    {
        for(size_t column = 0; column < columns; ++column )
        {
            std::cout << strings[row][column];
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}

// You will need a small helper function to make
// the "C" style pointer to pointers
template<std::size_t rows_v, std::size_t cols_v>
void func(std::array<std::array<char,cols_v>,rows_v>& strings)
{
    std::array<char*,cols_v> char_ptrs{};
    for(std::size_t row = 0; row < rows_v; ++row)
    {
        char_ptrs[row] = strings[row].data();
    }

    // and now you can call the legacy function
    legacy_func(char_ptrs.data(),rows_v,cols_v);
}

int main()
{
    std::array<std::array<char,3>,2> strings{{{'1','2','3'},{'4','5','6'}}};
    func(strings);
}


I would refactor func and split the array conversion code off.  func does two things, and the array conversion code can be written generically and tested seperately and maybe reused.  Then the remaining code is simple glue.

Sure, would be better for testability too

You have to create an array of pointers of size NUM_STRINGS that point to the start of each row of chars in order to use char ** indexing.
In the following example an array of pointers to chars is initialized by the function apc() which takes the 2D char array as an argument:
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

const int NUM_STRINGS{3}, MAX_LEN{2};

std::array<char*, NUM_STRINGS> apc(std::array<std::array<char, MAX_LEN>, NUM_STRINGS> &a2d) {
    std::array<char*, NUM_STRINGS> ret;
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STRINGS; i++)
        ret[i] = &a2d[i][0];
    return ret;
}

std::array<std::array<char, MAX_LEN>, NUM_STRINGS> c2d{ {{'a','b'},{'c','d'},{'e','f'}} };
std::array<char*, NUM_STRINGS> pac = apc(c2d);
char** ppc = &pac[0];

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_STRINGS; i++)
        std::cout << ppc[i][0] << ppc[i][1] << '\n';
}
/* outputs:
ab
cd
ef
*/


As a matter of taste, I'd have apc take its argument by address.  To stress that it operates on addresses.  Also apc could be written generically - take array of arrays, return array of pointers to first element.  That allows for better unit testing I suspect.
